# How to block all incoming request through one network interface?

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, interface

Saying I have a linux server as a router from LAN to WAN. 
I don't want any incoming WAN request for safety issue. 
So how should I block all the incoming request through the WAN interface, but doesn't limit the LAN users' normal internet activity?

Which application should I use? (`iptables`?). Which service will be interrupted if I shut up all incoming traffic?

Answer (score 15):

If you really want to block all incoming traffic from the WAN (or Internet), you can simply add a rule like the the following:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
```

assuming `eth0` is the WAN interface. This is enough to block all incoming traffic. However, you need to allow all related/established connections to be able to request some service from the WAN/Internet. So, you need a rule like:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Of course the `ACCEPT` rule should be added before the `DROP` rule. Doing so will prevent you from hosting any service within your network.

Comment: What do you mean by the last sentence "Doing so will you prevent you from hosting any service within your network"?  What if I do want to provide service for my LAN user?

Comment: I think what Khaled meant was that your server won't be able to proivde any services to the outside like FTP, HTTP, etc.

Comment: @hydroparadise: yes, that's right. Any connection from outside will be blocked.

Comment: This is incorrect and [Kranthi Guttikonda's answer](http://serverfault.com/a/775125/322144) is right. You need to add the `DROP` rule on the `INPUT` chain, not the `FORWARD` chain.

Answer (score 2):

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j DROP
```

Will not block incoming traffic. You should add rule on `INPUT` chain, *e.g.*:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
```